# Create preferencefrom single checkbox with without extending preferenceactivity

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

In my app i just have one basic setting from using a checkbox and i would like to have it persist itself just like preferences do when extending preferenceactivity, except without doing that. All the preference examples i can find , extend preferenceactivity.

Is it possible to have the preference functionality with just a basic checkbox in, with logic for it in Main UI? Short examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can save preferences manually yourself using **[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)**. You could then save/load the setting once the checkbox is changed

```
CheckBox checkBox = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.checkbox );
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // get the preference manager
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            // get the editor
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            // put the new setting
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, true);

            // IMPORTANT - save the new settings
            editor.commit();

         }  
      }
    }
});
```

You can then retrieve you setting where ever you like using

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
if (prefs.getBoolean(PREF_NAME, false)) {
   // setting dependent code goes here
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Argh didn't see your answer till I posted mine. Oops. haha

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the shared preferences in any activity...

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences( NameAsString, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean( keyAsString, value );
editor.apply();
```

note that editor.apply() is asynchronous and only available in GB and up, use editor.commit() for less than android 2.3

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("checkbox_key", isChecked);
        editor.commit();
    }
});
```